# How to use Count If function inside of a sub?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of times the string shows up in the range and return to worksheet 1. I am assuming this can be done in a Function () but I'm don't know how to write out the syntax.

```
Sub DistributedApps()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Dist As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row

    Dist = Application.Worksheets(3).WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("Y1:Y" & LastRow), "Distributed Apps")
    Worksheets(1).Range("N66:P69").Value = Dist
End Sub
```

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Dist = Application.Worksheets(3).WorksheetFunction...
> ```

The `Worksheets` property is returning an `Object` that could be either a `Sheets` collection (if given an array of sheet names) or a `Worksheet` object (if given one sheet name, or a sheet index), so you're getting a `Worksheet` object, but VBA only knows this at run-time.

Move that knowledge to compile-time by introducing a local `Worksheet` variable; note that `Application.Worksheets` will give you the sheets collection of whatever workbook is currently active, so it might be a good idea to make that more explicit by qualifying the member call with an actual `Workbook` object:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3)
```

Now that VBA knows what interface this object has, the editor can help you: when you type the dot in `sheet.`, you'll get a list of all members of the `Worksheet` interface - and see that none of them is `WorksheetFunction`: that is why error 438 is raised at run-time, the *object doesn't support this property*.

The `Application` object does have a `WorksheetFunction` member though, so [this will work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56687128/1188513).

```
lastRow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row
dist = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sheet.Range("Y1:Y" & lastRow), "Distributed Apps")
```

Note that the `Range` member call inside the `CountIf` argument list is also explicitly qualified with the `sheet` object. Without this qualifier, `Range` would be referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is<sup>1</sup>, and since you don't want to need to `Activate` any sheets for this to work, using an explicit worksheet object as a qualifier ensures you're computing the count off the correct sheet.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Unless that code is written in the code-behind for a `Worksheet` module - in which case the implicit qualifier is `Me` and the unqualified `Range` call is referring to *that* worksheet.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work.

```
Sub DistributedApps()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Dist As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets(3).Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row

    Dist = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(3).Range("Y1:Y" & LastRow), "Distributed Apps")
    Worksheets(1).Range("N66:P69").Value = Dist

End Sub
```

Comment: It should indeed! Kudos for qualifying that `Range` member call, and welcome to Stack Overflow! =)